# Display a loading spinner while DOM is being painted

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am working on a cordova android application, and would like to display some sort of loading message/spinner while the user's notifications are being loaded as there is a bit of a wait while the DOM is being painted with all the notifications.

We currently use the cg-busy directive in a few places to display spinners during wait times while ajax calls are being completed. However in this case, cg-busy doesn't accomplish what we want as the ajax call is very quick and it is the painting that is taking a long time.

So my question is this: is there some way to get cg-busy to display its spinner while the DOM is being painted or if not, is there something similar we could use to display a spinner during the paint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is showing a simple CSS animation until angular is done initializing. There are lots of plain CSS loading animations out there, you can just google some. I'll use one of [those](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) for this example.

So how does this work? I'm adding following `div` to my html:

```
<div class="loadingAnimation" ng-show="::false"></div>
```

And also following CSS:

```
.loadingAnimation {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-color: #3b454b;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: sk-scaleout 1.0s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-scaleout 1.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-scaleout {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes sk-scaleout {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Once angular is done initializing it will evaluate the ng-show and hide the loading animation. The `::` are just a performance improvement.

I'm not 100% sure if that's the behaviour you want, so you might want to tweak on the condition for `ng-show`. But I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works exactly how I need it to. Much appreciated.